# How to list blob files with newest first in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I've Googled, searched Microsoft documents, etc and just can't find the answer to this:

In Azure's own Portal, when you go to Storage -> Container -> and view Blob files. Then click a specific blob file and then click Versions, the portal lists the versions of this file OLDEST first. I have to click "load more" over and over and over again to finally get to the most recent version!

So my question is HOW can I list a blob file's versions with NEWEST first, at the top?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use storage explorer in the portal. Go to the storage account, click "Storage Explorer (preview)" on the left menu, and click on "Last Modified" to sort.

[image: Storage explorer in portal]

One other alternative is to use the Storage Explorer desktop app: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

Comment: Sorry, but the first suggestion only sorts the blob files. What I need to do is sort the VERSIONS of a single blob file. 

I'll try the app, but it's pretty messed up that the default isn't "newest first".

Comment: My apologies for misreading the question. I don't think there's a way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I've accepted this answer with a caveat: Only the "alternative" suggestion at the end is the real solution; Must use the desktop app.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is HOW can I list a blob file's versions with NEWEST
> first, at the top?!

Simple answer is that you can't. For blob versions, Azure Blob Storage always returns the blobs sorted by version id in ascending order. Considering version id is the date/time value when blob version was created, the oldest version is returned first. Furthermore Azure Blob Storage does not provide any server-side sorting feature.

If you are writing some code to fetch the blob versions, you will need to list all versions (taking continuation token into consideration) and sort it on the client side in descending order by version id in your code only.

Comment: Correct answer, you can't. But can by using the downloadable Storage Explorer app.

Comment: Please note that sorting would only work with the blobs listed/displayed. If you have more than 5000 blobs, then sorting may give you incorrect results.